# How to change tynimce or fck editor language?

Tags: php, tinymce, text-editor, fckeditor

How can I change tynimce or fck editor language. 
for eg :- How can I set hindi language
is it possible. any body knows the solution kindly help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no language package available for your language download the english one and replace the english strings with the correct word or phrase in your language. Plus you need to rename the files according to your language abbrevation code. In example for the german language you would rename the files `en.js` to `de.js` (well, german language package is available already). Then you could do the tinmymce community a great favor and submit your new language package [to moxiecode](http://www.moxiecode.com/contact.php) - the developer of tinymce, so that other users may use your translation.

Answer (score 2):

You could just download a localized package. Take a look here: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/i18n/index.php?ctrl=lang&act=download&pr_id=1

Answer (score 2):

Download the appropriate language pack (see cbrandolino's link, Hindi is available for TinyMCE) and set the language in your TinyMCE-init function:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    language : "de",
    ...
});
```